# How can I start phpMyAdmin?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-http-server, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have just installed phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu (using **sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin**). I think installation went OK. So, how can I start the phpMyAdmin now?

I tried http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/index.php

I also tried http://localhost/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php

Both do not work.

I also need to add that I have installed Apache, PHP and MySQL. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the file phpMyAdmin.conf to something like this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   order deny,allow
   #deny from all
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

or `allow from <your IP address>` if you intend to host this server.

Comment: I see only "lighttpd.conf" and "apache.conf". The content of "phpMyAdmin.conf" is similar to you example (there is "<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>"). But there are not "order" or "allow". Should I add them? Where can I learn the syntax (I do not want to add something I do not understand).

Comment: If `Allow` doesn't exist you need to add them. A simple Google search for "phpMyAdmin.conf" should yield plenty of samples.

Answer (score 8):

In ubuntu by default, phpmyadmin is installed in /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Setting a symbolic link should help you. The command would be as follows :

$ ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin

After this, open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` in browser and it should work (given that your Apache settings permit this)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ ?

Comment: This works for me.